vba code in excel unable to automatically select the listbox item after input data into the search field with selenium
I want to automatically select the specific listbox item after I input the keyword into the search input box, just like my attached photo, but it is failed after I tried to use the findelementbyId or findelementbyXpath.
Here's my code:
driver.Wait 500
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='property-tag']").SendKeys ("Casa Green")

driver.Wait 500
**driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ui-id-18']").Click**

The error message I got is:
Run-time error '7'
No SuchElementError
Element not found for Xpath=//*[@id='ui-id-18']
Script:
enter image description here
I want to automatically select the specific listbox item after I input the keyword into the search input box

the screenshot doesn't show any elements with id='property-tag' or id='ui-id-18'.  It's hard to say what's happening, but in general using explicit webdriverwaits with expected condition will help.  (right-click in browser, choose "Inspect" when the auto-suggest is visible and copy/paste that code into your question... )

driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ui-id-18']").Click,  I just found that this xpath is keep changing everytime I loaded it. I tried to copy XPath from right click when the option of the listbox appeared, but when I tried to inspect it and copy Xpath, the result gave me is //[@id="ui-id-6"]. However, I tried to toggle breakpoint before driver.FindElementByXPath("//[@id='ui-id-6']").Click, and change the new Xpath, but finally it got error message, Runtime Error 11, ElementNotVisibleError, element not interactable.

no one can help?

are you using explicit webdriverwaits now?:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/  If you find that the id is not predictable you need to think a bit like the user.  How do they decide what to click?  Craft your selector accordingly... sometimes this may involve part path-based and part attribute/text based selector.  It will also help to try/catch exceptions.   The exceptions in Selenium a very well designed and will help you troubleshoot problems.

@brosermator, Sorry, I am still new in vba code & Selenium, I dont really understand your advise, can you have sample on it or the solution to my coding? Appreciate it if can help

Can't give specifics... but since you are new to vba, I would stop using it.  You'll have less trouble using Java, Python, or C#.  You might also learn HTML and about the DOM.  That'll help you create selectors.  In this case it looks a bit like jQuery... you might learn a bit about JS and jQuery, too.  It may help you to understand DOM manipulation.... which will help you to craft selectors and understand Selenium's exceptions better.
